# Probability of the first digit of $X$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$. Let $Y$ be the first digit of $X$. Show that $P(Y = 0) = .1$  (Hint: $P(Y = 0) = P(0\le X <.1)$ Why?).

Hello, I don't really understand how to approach this question here. Uniform distribution means that the probability of anything is $1/(b - a)$ and in this case $b = 1$ and $a = 0$. But What do they mean by "first digit of $X$"? And why is $ P(Y = 0) = P(0<=X <.1)$, or specifically, why is $.1$ used and not $0.01$ or even $0.001$?

Comment: "*The first digit of X*" is in this context surely referring to the tenths-place digit, the number immediately following the decimal point.  For examples, the tenths-place digit of $0.\color{red}{5}37$ is $5$ and the tenths-place digit of $0.\color{red}{0}88$ is $0$.  It should be clear then that all numbers in the range $(0,0.1)$ such as $0.05$ have their tenths-place digits equal to zero.  All numbers in the range $(0.1,0.2)$ such as $0.15$ will have their tenths-place digits equal to $1$ and so on.

Comment: It might be a bit ambiguous as to numbers like $0.099999999\dots=0.1$ whether the tenths-place digit should be considered $0$ or should be considered $1$ (*under most reasonable definitions it will be $1$*), but thankfully even with possible ambiguity there it doesn't matter since such numbers form a nullset with probability zero here and so can be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear.

By the first digit, it means the first digit after the decimal point.

Example of numbers between $[0,0.1)$ and numbers such as $0.\color{blue}01$ and $0.\color{blue}03$.

Example of numbers between $[0.1, 0.2)$ numbers such as $0.\color{blue}12$ and $0.\color{blue}15$.

With that hopefully you can answer the question.

Extra question: What is the probability that the first digit begins with $5$?

Comment: this answer is structured correctly but is incorrect

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. But I have provided all the information provided. Thanks for explaining though! 

Is the $P(Y = 5) = P(Y = 0) = 0.1?$

Comment: @sasaasasasha the punchline is that yes... $P(Y=k)=0.1$ for all $k\in\{0,1,2,3,\dots,9\}$ since the event $Y=k$ is equal to the event $x\in [\frac{k}{10},\frac{k+1}{10})$ which is an interval of length $0.1$, by definition.

Comment: Thank you everyone!